# How to get a date out of a string?

Tags: r

I have a file with name "test_result_20210930.xlsx". I would like to get "20210930" out to a new variable `date`. How should I do that? I think I can say `pattern="[0-9]+"` What if I have more numbers in the file name, and I only want the part that will stand for the date? (8digt together?)

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `gsub` with `\\D+` matches all non-digits and in the replacement, specify blank (`""`)

```
gsub("\\D+", "", str1)
[1] "20210930"
```

If the pattern also includes other digits, and want to return only the 8 digits

```
 sub(".*_(\\d{8})_.*", "\\1", "test_result_20210930_01.xlsx")
[1] "20210930"
```

---

Or use `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract("test_result_20210930_01.xlsx", "(?<=_)\\d{8}(?=_)")
[1] "20210930"
```

---

If we need to automatically convert to `Date` object

```
library(parsedate)
parse_date(str1)
[1] "2021-09-30 UTC"
```

-output

```
str1 <- "test_result_20210930.xlsx"
```

Comment: what if `str1 <- "test_result_20210930_01.xlsx"`? in this case, we only want the digits chunk that are 8 digits connected.

Comment: @Stataq updated

Comment: Change your pattern to "\\D+(\\d{8}).+"

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `str_extract` from the `stringr` package to obtain the desired result.

```
library(stringr)
str_extract("test_result_20210930.xlsx", "[0-9]{8}")

# [1] "20210930"
```